# Authentication Error when trying to reset password - django

Tags: python, django, web, gmail

I try to reset password with gmail.com. I think I set everything correct, but it's still doesn't work and raise error like so: [image: as you can see here]

*settings.py*

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

I set my enviroment variables `EMAIL_USER` (login to my gmail account) and `EMAIL_PASS` (16-sign password provided by Google when you use 2-step authentication - Google App Password). I tried also use password to my gmail account but this also not work. Someone know what I do wrong ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't use the django default for sending emails, I use smtplib to connect to he SMTP server and the email module for building the email. However my SMTP server port is 465 (for gmail) so try that?? If that doesn't work try just connecting to the SMTP server directly:

Open python then

`import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
account=os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
password=os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
server.login(account,password)`

See if that connects ok

Comment: Just a check: Does your gmail account have MFA enabled by any chance?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, MFA is enebled. I generated this 16-sign password and I try to log in using it. But as I see on my gmail account, it wasn't used yet, so something works wrong.

Comment: Note that the password shown has dashes (`-`) to make it easily readable, but you must not put dashes in your code.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, I know that. I tried write it as one continuous expression as well as 4 sign parts divided by space but none of this works.

Comment: @KJTHoward Port 465 is for SSL where 587 is for TLS. It is specified at Gmail Help. I changed port at 465 and connect manually in django shell but I get an error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\smtplib.py", line 638, in auth
    authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I'm using port 587 with `EMAIL_USE_TSL` set to `True` and an app password and this works perfectly. Note that I only actually connect to gmail SMTP from my production environment, not from my local environment. I'm not sure that makes a difference.

Comment: See if [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) helps. Maybe localhost is treated as less secure app and that's why it works when running on a production machine where there's a domain attached.

Comment: The error message mentions `webmaster@localhost` - it looks as if you haven't set `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` in your settings. Many email providers, including Google, will only let you send from an email address that matches your account, to prevent spam.

Comment: I would also use `os.environ['...']` - if you use `os.environ.get(...)` then it will silently return `None` when the environment variable isn't set.

Comment: I discovered that there is a problem with fetching data from os.environ.get(), because I can send email if I hardcode my login and password in settings.py. I don't know why it doesn't work, that's weird. When I test os.environ.get() somewhere else it's works as it should.

@Alasdair this notation (os.environ['EMAIL_USER']) is incorrect, I get KeyError when I use it.

Comment: `os.environ['EMAIL_USER']` *is* correct. If it gives a key error, that means that the environment variable is not set. Now you have the key error, you can investigate why the environment variable is not set. The disadvantage of `os.environ.get(...)` is that it silently returns `None`, which meant you spent lots of time looking at other things before you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the EMAIL_PORT to be 465

```
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

Using smtplib to connect directly to the gmail stmp server it fails with port 587 but works with 465:

```
server=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
account="MY ACCOUNT LOG IN"
password="MY APP PASSWORD"
server.login(account, password)
```

returns:

```
(235, b'2.7.0 Accepted')
```

However

```
server=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
account="MY ACCOUNT LOG IN"
password="MY APP PASSWORD"
server.login(account, password)
```

Gives a time out error. And connecting without SSL isn't supported for gmail:

```
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
account="MY ACCOUNT LOG IN"
password="MY APP PASSWORD"
server.login(account, password)
```

Returns

```
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Comment: If you set `EMAIL_USE_TLS`, Django isn't using `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` but `smtplib.SMTP`. It then does `starttls()` before `login()`. Port 587 is correct. For implementation details, see __django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend.open()__